# Does DirectX9 define something to differentiate versions at preprocessor?

Tags: c++, directx

As Visual Studio defined `_MSC_VER`, `1700` stands for VS2012 while `1800` stands for VS2013.

Does DirectX9 define something to differentiate between **(December 2004)** and **(June 2010)**?

Comment: No, what do you need that for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, but I guess that `D3D_SDK_VERSION` and `D3DX_SDK_VERSION` defines is that you are looking for. At least in this example it's used to check a [runtime vs. build versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172717%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
HRESULT CD3DXMyApplication::Initialize(HINSTANCE hInstance, 
  LPCSTR szWindowName, LPCSTR szClassName, UINT uWidth, UINT uHeight)
{
    HRESULT hr;

    if (!D3DXCheckVersion(D3D_SDK_VERSION, D3DX_SDK_VERSION))
        return E_FAIL;

    //...
}
```

Comment: I had checked D3D_SDK_VERSION is 32 both in (December 2004) and (June 2010).

Comment: No, this function will not tell you which version of the SDK you installed.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to differentiate at preprocessor time.

Comment: @cbel could it be `D3DX_SDK_VERSION` then?